# About the pointwise convergence of the divided difference function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

When I'm reading the book Real Analysis of Royden, I don't understand why he can implies that $\{ \text{Diff}_{1/n} f \}$ converges pointwise a.e. on $[a,b]$ to the derivative of $f$.

I mean do we have any rigorous explanation? This is the corollary that I'm reading. [image]

I think we need to show that

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \text{Diff}_{1/n} f = \overline{D}f$ a.e on $[a,b]$, where $\overline{D}f$ is the upper derivative of $f$. But how can we do it?

For the derivative of $f$, as well as upper and lower derivative, I use the definition from Royden, too.
[image]

And when $\overline{D}f = \underline{D}f$, we say $f$ is differentiable and $f'=\overline{D}f = \underline{D}f$.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is differentiable ae. For those points ${ f(x+{1 \over n}) - f(x) \over {1 \over n}} \to f'(x)$.

Comment: @copper.hat  what do you mean when you write $f'(x)$?

Comment: The derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x$?

Comment: I added more information about the derivative I use, which means I need to prove the sequence converges to $\overline{D}f$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove Lebesgue's theorem (monotone function on an open interval is differentiable ae.)? If it is differentiable ae. then $\text{Diff}_{1 \over n} f$ converges to $f'$ ae.

Comment: No, I have proved it before I read the corollary. My question is how to prove the sequence converges pointwise to $f'$, which is defined as above.

Comment: And how do you know for sure $\text{Diff}_{1/n} f$ converges to $f$'?

Comment: If $f'(x)$ exists then it must converge. I am confused. Perhaps $\text{Diff}_{1 \over n} f$ is something other than ${ f(x+{1 \over n}) - f(x) \over {1 \over n}} $?

Comment: And how do you know for sure it must converge? I mean is there any rigorous explanation?

Comment: That is what $f'$ means.

Comment: $\text{Diff}_{1/n}f$ is exact as you write. But how do you implies it must converge to $\overline{D}f$?

Comment: My question is how can we show that it must converge to $\overline{D}f$?

Comment: $f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(x+h) -f(x) \over h}$. Then for any sequence $h_n \to 0$ you have ${f(x+h_n) -f(x) \over h_n} \to f'(x)$. Equality of $\bar{D}f$, $\text{Diff}_{1 \over n} f$ follows from this. The 'hard' part is showing that $f'(x)$ exists ae.

Comment: I see my problems. Because in this case, we consider $f'$ is not as usual. I have added more information.

Comment: $f'$ here is defined as $\overline{D}f = \underline{D}f$, not as the usual sense you write.

Comment: I think you need to show that $f'$ exists **iff** $\overline{D}f = \underline{D}f$. Messy, but straightforward.

Comment: I got it. I were totally confused until you say.

Comment: :-), good luck! ${}$